# defining statics function (like in mongoose) in mySql using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, sequelize.js

Trying to define a function inside the model so that I can have a common set of functions.Here is my code for my table. I am using sequelize ORM and nodejs

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var AttendantUser = sequelize.define('AttendantUser', {
    user_id : {
      type : DataTypes.CHAR(36),
      defaultValue : DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey : true
    },
    mobile : {
        type : DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull : false,
        unique : true
    },
    reset_code : {
      type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull : true,
      defaultValue : '0000'
    }
  },{
    freezeTableName : true,
    paranoid : true
  });


AttendantUser.usernameInUse = function (callback) {
 console.log("fefe");
 callback(null, "hello");
 }
  return AttendantUser;
};
```

The error I get when I try to use usernameInUse function is .
error: mModels.usernameInUse is not a function

Comment: Have you checked out Hooks? http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/hooks/

Comment: What is the `mModels` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what classMethods are for. Look for the option "[options.classMethods]" at the [Sequelize documentation page](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/).

This is what your code must look like:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var AttendantUser = sequelize.define('AttendantUser', {
    user_id : {
      type : DataTypes.CHAR(36),
      defaultValue : DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey : true
    },
    mobile : {
        type : DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull : false,
        unique : true
    },
    reset_code : {
      type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull : true,
      defaultValue : '0000'
    }
  },{
    freezeTableName : true,
    paranoid : true,
    classMethods : {
       usernameInUse = function (callback) {
            console.log("fefe");
            callback(null, "hello");
            return this;
       }
    }
  });
```

After **syncing** with the database, you can import the model with

```
AttendantUser = require('/path/to/attendant-user');
```

You can then call the static method like so:

```
AttendantUser.usernameInUse(() => {console.log('callback called.');})
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Sequelize V4](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html). It looks different than V3.

`classMethods` and `instanceMethods` options were removed from sequelize.define. Sequelize models are now ES6 classes. You can set class / instance level methods like this:

**Old**

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

**New**

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});

// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}
```

Comment: this question should be marked as answer... the other is way too old and i got a lot of troubles... can you please end a link to the docs where talks about that? cuz i didnt find :c

Comment: @nishi Updated now